# Can too many background images decrease YOLOv5 model performance?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

I have a dataset with many background images (those without labels), at least 50% of all images in the dataset. Now I read in the YOLOv5 tutorials that it is recommended that about 10% of the whole dataset are such background images. But in my dataset it would be quite difficult to identify all those background images.

Thus, if a dataset includes that many background images, would that just extend training time, or would it also have a negative impact on the overall model training performance?

Answer (score 0):

It will have negative impact on the overall model training performance. The recommended way is correct. You don't need to identify or label these backgrounds. Just add them as negative images to your dataset.Simply put (background)images with no label or empty label in your dataset. It will decrease the false positives.